# UITextField Programmatically won't convert into string or take any binary operators Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, xcode11

Prior to having this issue, I was using storyboards and outlets for text fields. However, I found it easier to work on my app programmatically.  Unfortunately, as I began to convert my app such as by programmatically making a text field I ran into some issues as I still have some functions such as my login function that was made for the text fields from the storyboards.  I'm still new swift so any solutions would be helpful.

I declared my email text field as such:

```
    var emailTxt: UITextField!
```

The other aspects of the email text field are as such in the view did load function:

```
    emailTxt = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 77.0, y: 306.0, width: 262, height: 34))
    emailTxt.backgroundColor = .white
    emailTxt.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    emailTxt.keyboardAppearance = .light
    emailTxt.keyboardType = .emailAddress
    emailTxt.placeholder = "Email"
    emailTxt.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
    emailTxt.textColor = .systemGreen
    emailTxt.tintColor = .systemGreen
    emailTxt.delegate = self

    self.view.addSubview(emailTxt)
```

Text field functions outside the view did load:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Finally the area where I get the issues.

First, it says that for the guard statement there must be an else statement.

Then it says (Binary operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UITextField?' and 'String') Then in the else statement it says (Closure expression is unused)

Finally, in the auth statement it gives the error: Cannot convert value of type 'UITextField' to expected argument type 'String' while underlining the email

Here is the code for that:

```
    guard let email = emailTxt
    email != "",
    let password = passwordTxt
    password != ""
        else {
            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Missing Info", message: "Please fill out all fields")
            return

    }

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: {(user, error) in
        guard error == nil else {
            AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is self explanatory, you are trying to use the `UITextField` type as `String`. Here what you need to use is the `.hasText` property of `UIKeyInput` protocol which `UITextField` conforms to. Here's how:

```
guard emailTxt.hasText,
passwordTxt.hasText
    else {
        AlertController.showAlert(self, title: "Missing Info", message: "Please fill out all fields")
        return
}
let email = emailTxt.text!
let password = passwordTxt.text!
```

You can force unwrap the text of `UITextField` because it defaults to empty String `""`. Even if it's set to `nil` it returns an empty string.

Comment: UITextField `text` property default value is an empty string. It will NEVER return nil

Comment: `UIKeyInput` has a property called hasText exactly for this purpose `guard emailTxt.hasText` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext

Comment: I think I've read this somewhere that it's ok to force unwrap the optional `.text`. Then why is the text property still an optional?

Comment: yes you can force unwrap it. Even if you assign nil to the text property it will return an empty string right after that

Comment: "Then why is the text property still an optional?" This allows you to assign an optional string to it without the need to unwrap it

Comment: @LeoDabus I’d be wary about depending on this implicit behaviour of nil being „magically” converted into empty string. This happens because UIKit (and so UITextField) is still written in Obj-C, and this conversion is part of making the interop safer. If this ever changes, this code may start to crash. Implicitly unwrapping optionals should always be used with extreme caution, preferrably only in relation to code you control.

Comment: @Losiowaty I disagreed. This will never change. You can check the documentation which states the default value is an empty string.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `.text` property.

```
guard let email = emailTxt.text, !email.isEmpty else {
    // show alert
    return
}
```

As of **iOS 10**, it can also simply be written as:

```
guard emailTxt.hasText else {
    // show alert
    return
}
```

*Credit to @LeoDabus for pointing that out*

Comment: UITextField text property default value is an empty string. It will NEVER return nil

Comment: @user12985516 `UIKeyInput` has a property called hasText exactly for that `guard emailTxt.hasText` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext

Comment: @LeoDabus I was not even aware of that property.  I see it was added in iOS10.  Thank you, as I have been writing it like that for years.